# Machine Learner Wizard missing in WSO2 IoT Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-iot, wso2-ml

According to https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Analyzing+Data I should be able to do some Machine Learning tasks in IoT Server but the menu, usually available in WSO2 DAS, is missing, as is the Machine Learner features in "Configure->Features->Installed features" or "Configure->Features->Available features".

What Can I do?

Should I use an external DAS, as described here https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Configuring+WSO2+IoT+Server+with+WSO2+Data+Analytics+Server?

Answer (score 0):

Its depending on the load of the events and number of IOT devices you are dealing. If the load is not significant, you can install WSO2 DAS features in the IOT node and operate.

Going forward it will be difficult when scale up, in case you if the IOT event generating throughput is high whereas you need to have multiple nodes and clustering. Therefore simply you can setup another DAS node as in the documentation and publish events from the IOT server and leave the analytic part there. When scaling up you can have different clusters for IOT and for analytics depending on the load.

Comment: Which values should I set for carbon.device.mgt.version and carbon.device.mgt.plugin.version in analytics-feature-installation.pom available at https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Configuring+WSO2+IoT+Server+with+WSO2+Data+Analytics+Server?